# Tshark/wireshark on an ephemeral interface

Tags: interface, point-to-point-protocol, tshark

Our server hosts a VPN. Each connection to the VPN creates a new PPP interface (ppp0, ppp1, etc.) and the connections are ephemeral in the sense that the interface can go up or down intermittently.

What we need is a way to capture packets using tshark for all ppp interfaces even though they may go up or down intermittently.

Any ideas or solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture packets from the `any` interface. That will give you all packets regardless of which interface they were sent or received on. Then you can apply a capture filter to ignore those packets, you are not interested in. For example `! (host 127.0.0.1 || host ::1)` would ignore all packets on the lo interface.

Comment: Will this dynamically include new interfaces?